# Foreign key not being recognized

Tags: django, django-models

I've created two models. When I run makemigrations, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERRORS:
userorders.UserCartItem: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'userorders.UserCart.items', but it does not have a foreign key to 'UserCart' or 'UserService'.
```

models.py

```
class UserCartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None) 
    cart = models.ForeignKey("UserCart", on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    line_item_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class UserCart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None) 
    items = models.ManyToManyField(UserService, through=UserCartItem)          
    items_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Any thoughts on what the problem is? I've defined the foreign key on UserCartItem as UserCart, but it looks like it's not being recognized. I should point out that I understand that when you identify another model as a foreign key and the foreign key model is below the model that you are working in, you have to put the foreign key model in quotation marks, hence why I used quotation marks in this line:

```
models.ForeignKey("UserCart", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add default=None:

```
models.ForeignKey("UserCart", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```